# Do US PS1 Games downloaded from Playstation Network work on a PAL PS3 Console

Tags: region-lock, persona-2-eternal-punishment

i've been reading up on Shin Megami Tensei Persona 2 Innocent Sin and released that unlike the Snow Queen Quest in the previous game, Shin Megami Tensei Person 2 Eternal Punishment carries on after the vents of Innocent Sin

now Eternal Punishment has been re-released on PSP but only in Japan and only the US has it on PlayStation Network (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona_2#Eternal_Punishment)),Ii have a PAL PS3 console, while PS3 games are region free and PS1 Physical Games still have Region Restriction I am wondering, if I was to buy and download Eternal Punishment from the US Store, would it work on my PAL PS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, to my knowledge ([additional proof](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3/PS1-games-region-free-for-PS3/m-p/19867453#M3250303)) PSN games (even if they are PS1 games) are NOT region locked, so you can buy and play them on any PS3 console.